# Oracle xml manipulation using Java

Tags: java, xml, oracle

Having an Oracle database with a table STUDENT, which has a field STUDEN_NAME, is there a way to retrieve it enclosed in XML tags?

```
select STUDENT_NAME from STUDENT;

res.getString("STUDENT_NAME"); // I want: <StudenName>PAUL</StudentName>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select xmlelement("StudentName", STUDENT_NAME) from STUDENT;
```

A Google search for

> oracle result set as xml

Turned up the *Oracle XML DB Developer's Guide*, specifically chapter 18, entitled *Generating XML Data from the Database* - from where I got the syntax shown above.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add in your java code use: `res.getString(1)`.

Comment: no real need. He can just alias the query column and still use the name.

Comment: rs.getString("STUDEN_NAME"); and rs.getString(1); returns null (but the table contains names) ¿?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to make the actual change in the query then the following will give you what you are looking for:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT("StudentName",student_name) student_name FROM student;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me comes using getClobVal;

```
select XMLELEMENT("StudentName", STUDENT_NAME).getClobVal() STUDENT_NAME from STUDENT
```